# Does this circuit have a good enough ESD protection to protect I2C line or do I need a series resistor?

Tags: i2c, circuit-protection, esd

I want to be able to run a wire to an I2C device as far as posible for learning purposes, but I also want to know how to protect the I2C line from ESD events to exceed level 4 of IEC 61000-4-2.

I am using a 3.3 V to 5V buffer (PCA9509DP, 118) to increase range and for 5V compatibility. For protection I am using a TVS array (SRV05-4-P-T7).

Does this circuit have a good enough ESD protection to protect I2C line or do I need a series resistor?

[image]
I2C circuit schematic

Comment: The ESD protection being "good enough" I can't comment really, as it looks good to me. The I2C bus part is what worries me, there are no pull-ups and the PCA extenders are paralleled for two 5V buses. Be sure to read if the extender can be used like that. And how much is "as far as possible" and at what speed rate? Because it depends on cabling and if you wire the cabling in good or bad way.

Comment: You are right I wil use a 10k pull up resistor at channel B just in case. Channel A of the buffer does not need a pull up. I am going to be using standard speed (100kHz). I wil do a test with different sensors and cables. I do not think that connecting two of the buffers to 5V matter.

Comment: But there must be pull-ups somewhere on the A side, if not on this board. It does not work if there are no pull-ups. And I did not mean the problem is connecting two buffers in parallel to 5V, I meant two buffers on same A bus.You must carefully read the datasheet if you can have two buffers on same bus like that - they use some weird tricks to work and if you parallel the two they may not work properly.

Comment: I read the datasheet a few times. it stated " port(channel) B is interoperable with all I2C-bus slaves, masters and repeaters. " Port A or channel was not clear to me. For this reason I am deciding to only use one buffer. This wil also save me about €7.5 for the 5 PCB.  I wil test what the capebility of the PCB is when it arives.